# Why is calculating based on a large number read by clap::Parser slower than when that number is hardcoded?

Tags: rust

I have a really simple program that take an integer argument from the command line and perform the following task:

```rust
use clap::Parser ;

#[derive(Parser,Default)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short)]
    number: u128
}

fn sum(n: u128) -> u128 {
    let mut result: u128 = 0;
    for i in 1..n { result += n/i; }
    result 
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse() ;
    println!("{}", sum(args.number)) ;
}
```

Fairly simple, right? Well, when executing it for "large" numbers, let's say 999999999 for example, it takes almost ten seconds on my machine to get the result.

```
$ time ./target/release/main -n 999999999
20877697533

real    0m9.442s
user    0m9.370s
sys     0m0.030s
```

However, if I suppress any use of clap and hard-code the value

```rust
fn sum(n: u128) -> u128 {
    let mut result: u128 = 0;
    for i in 1..n { result += n/i; }
    result 
}

fn main() {
    let n: u128 = 999999999 ;
    println!("{}", sum(n)) ;
}
```

the execution time drops to around two seconds

```
$ time ./target/release/main
20877697533

real    0m2.398s
user    0m2.236s
sys     0m0.013s
```

So, what makes the clap version so slow?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I'm not sure it relates to clap at all. More likely it's a question of compile-time vs runtime calculation; when the number is known at compile time, that means the compiler can precalculate and otherwise optimize.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting 1.9s for the `args.number` argument, and 0.65s for the fixed `n` version. The `Args::parse()` part has no measurable impact on the runtime, only using the value from it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If it was compile-time calculations, it should be near instantaneous.

Comment: _shrug_. Right thing to do is to stop speculating, [pull out a profiler](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/profiling.html), and _measure_ where the time goes in either case.

Comment: Worth noting if you add a tiny bit of indirection in there that the compiler can't immediately optimize (somehow) you get the slow behaviour, like `let n : u128 = "999999999".parse().unwrap()` has the same effect.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `clap`, that's for sure. When I generated a random n in the same order of magnitude it also takes very long. Probably compiler isn't able to properly optimize `sum` function, when it doesn't know n.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I'm curious what optimizations can be done for a "fixed" `n` that still involves spending quite some time churning out the result. Is there some kind of overflow check that can be omitted?

Comment: I think there's some kind of check being done in the "dynamic" version, while in the fixed version it's omitted. If you switch to `f64` then the "type" of `n` passed in has zero effect, as `f64` won't overflow the same way. Worth checking the assembly output of each version to compare.

Comment: Quick look with [flamegraph](https://crates.io/crates/flamegraph) tells that when n is not specified *majority* of time is spent in `compiler_builtins::int::specialized_div_rem::u128_by_u64_div_rem`. Why is that? I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

999999999 fits into a 32-bit integer. With the hard-coded value, the compiler notices this and demotes all operations to 32-bit operations, which are *far* faster to execute than the 128-bit routines, which have no native compiler support.

Compare the assembly for the non-hardcoded loop (but with clap removed, as in Schwern's version):

```
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    cmpq    $2, %r15
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    sbbq    $0, %rax
    movl    $0, %r13d
    jb  .LBB5_9
    movq    %r15, %rsi
    addq    $-1, %rsi
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    adcq    $-1, %rdi
    movq    %r15, %rax
    addq    $-2, %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rcx
    adcq    $-1, %rcx
    movq    %rsi, 32(%rsp)
    andl    $3, %esi
    movq    %rsi, 40(%rsp)
    cmpq    $3, %rax
    sbbq    $0, %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 8(%rsp)
    jae .LBB5_4
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    movl    $1, %edx
    xorl    %r13d, %r13d
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    jmp .LBB5_6

.LBB5_4:
    andq    $-4, 32(%rsp)
    movl    $1, %edx
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    xorl    %r13d, %r13d
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    movq    %rdi, 64(%rsp)

.LBB5_5:
    movq    %rbx, 88(%rsp)
    movq    %rsi, 96(%rsp)
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rsp)
    movq    %rdx, (%rsp)
    addq    $1, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rsp)
    movq    %rcx, %rbx
    adcq    $0, %rbx
    movq    %r15, %rdi
    movq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    (%rsp), %rdx
    movq    16(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    __udivti3@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r14
    callq   *%r14
    movq    %r14, %r8
    movq    %rax, %r14
    movq    %rdx, %r12
    addq    %rbp, %r14
    adcq    %r13, %r12
    movq    (%rsp), %rax
    addq    $2, %rax
    movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    adcq    $0, %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    movq    %r15, %rdi
    movq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    24(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rbx, %rcx
    movq    %r8, %rbx
    callq   *%r8
    movq    %rbx, %r8
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    %r15, %r13
    movq    %rdx, %rbp
    addq    %r14, %rbx
    adcq    %r12, %rbp
    movq    (%rsp), %rax
    addq    $3, %rax
    movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    movq    16(%rsp), %r15
    adcq    $0, %r15
    movq    %r13, %rdi
    movq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    80(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    72(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %r8, %r14
    callq   *%r8
    movq    %r14, %r8
    movq    %rax, %r12
    movq    %rdx, %r14
    addq    %rbx, %r12
    adcq    %rbp, %r14
    addq    $4, (%rsp)
    adcq    $0, 16(%rsp)
    movq    %r13, %rdi
    movq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    24(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %r15, %rcx
    movq    %r13, %r15
    callq   *%r8
    movq    88(%rsp), %rbx
    movq    96(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    64(%rsp), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rbp
    movq    %rdx, %r13
    movq    (%rsp), %rdx
    addq    %r12, %rbp
    adcq    %r14, %r13
    addq    $4, %rsi
    adcq    $0, %rbx
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    xorq    32(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rbx, %rcx
    xorq    %rdi, %rcx
    orq %rax, %rcx
    movq    16(%rsp), %rcx
    jne .LBB5_5

.LBB5_6:
    cmpq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    movq    %rbp, %rsi
    je  .LBB5_9
    xorl    %r12d, %r12d
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    movq    %rdx, %rbx
    movq    %rcx, %r14

.LBB5_8:
    movq    %rsi, (%rsp)
    addq    $1, %rbx
    adcq    $0, %r14
    movq    %r15, %rdi
    movq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   *__udivti3@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    movq    (%rsp), %rsi
    addq    %rax, %rsi
    adcq    %rdx, %r13
    addq    $1, %r12
    adcq    $0, %rbp
    movq    %r12, %rax
    xorq    40(%rsp), %rax
    orq %rbp, %rax
    movq    %rbx, %rdx
    movq    %r14, %rcx
    jne .LBB5_8
```

to the hardcoded loop:

```
.LBB5_1:
    movl    $999999999, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    %r8d
    movl    %eax, %r9d
    addq    %rcx, %r9
    adcq    $0, %rdi
    addq    $2, %r10
    adcq    $0, %r11
    leal    1(%r8), %ecx
    movl    $999999999, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    %ecx
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    addq    %r9, %rcx
    adcq    $0, %rdi
    cmpq    $999999997, %r8
    sbbq    $0, %rsi
    movq    %r10, %r8
    movq    %r11, %rsi
    jb  .LBB5_1
    subq    $88, %rsp
    movq    %rcx, 24(%rsp)
    movq    %rdi, 32(%rsp)
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq    core::fmt::num::<impl core::fmt::Display for u128>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
    movq    $2, 64(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    movq    $1, 80(%rsp)
    leaq    40(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   *std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    addq    $88, %rsp
    retq
```

Note in particular the total lack of calls to `__udivti3` in this version.

Answer (score 1):

```
fn main() {
    let n: u128 = 999999999 ;
    println!("{}", sum(n)) ;
}
```

With this version, `n` is known at compile time and the compiler can optimize `sum` for it.

We can test this by removing `clap` and doing our own command line parsing. This is just as slow as the `clap` version.

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{}", sum(u128::from_str(&args[2]).unwrap()));
}
```